# What's that CS "big word" term for the same action always having the same effect

Tags: language-agnostic, computer-science, terminology, vocabulary

There's a computer science term for this that escapes my head, one of those words that ends with "-icity".

It means something like a given action will always produce the same result, IE there won't be any hysteresis, or the action will not alter the functioning of the system...

Ring a bell, anyone? Thanks.

<sub>Apologies for the tagging, I'm only tagging it Java b/c I learned about this in a Java class back in school and I figure that crowd tends to have more CS background...</sub>

Comment: I think he means the word for a function that always returns the same result, given the same parameters (ex. sqrt). I cannot remember the word either... It is used in compiler optimization theory, it's not *'deterministic'* or *'idempotent'* though.

Comment: Or since he mentioned hysteresis, he might be thinking of atomicity. A little help, OP?

Comment: @BlueRaja: what you describe is a *pure function*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Comment: @Stephan:  Yes, that is it.  For some reason, I remember my compiler professor calling it something else..

Comment: @BlueRaja: ...which is in turn related to Referential transparency (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29) and indeed compiler optimization theory.

Comment: @ambertch: so what was the solution in the end?? :-)

Comment: The Java crowd "tends to have more CS background" than who?  Not my experience at all, by the way...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This could mean two different things:

**deterministic** - meaning that given the same initial state, the same operation (with exactly the same data) will always produce the same resulting state (and optional output.) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm

i.e. same action has the same effect - assuming you start from the same place in the same system. (Nothing random about it, nothing fed in from the outside that could effect the result...)

**idempotent** - meaning applying a function to a value once e.g. f(x) = v produces the same result as applying the function multiple times e.g. f(f(f(x))) = v  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

i.e. one or more function applications yields the same value given the same initial value

Comment: I though deterministic just mens it does not crash :-) given the same starting state and input. (Joking)

Comment: Yes! I was looking for idempotent - I guess it's not exactly what I thought it meant though, thanks!

Comment: for example, some light switches are idempotent, some are not.  If you flip it up to turn it on, and flip it up again, it stays on, that's idempotent.  If you press it to turn it on, then press it again, it turns off - that's not idempotent.

Answer (score 11):

you mean [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) ??

Comment: That has to do with side effects, but not necessarily that it gives the same result.

Comment: from wikipedia:Idempotence (pronounced /ˌaɪdɨmˈpoʊtəns/) describes the property of operations in mathematics and computer science that means that multiple applications of the operation do not change the result.

Answer (score 11):

[Referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29) is also used in some CS circles.

Answer (score 8):

[Nullipotent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nullipotent)?

Comment: This is the one that fits the criteria of the question. +1

Comment: I guess to really fit the question you have to say Nullipotenticity

Comment: Ahaha, true. I'm too lazy to edit, though, do forgive me. :-)

Answer (score 6):

deterministic ,.,-=

Comment: Deterministic still may alter the system.  `myAccount.balance += 50` would deterministically withdraw money from account ;-)

Comment: I'd like to be able to withdrawal money while increasing my balance!

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for **invariant**?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29

> In computer science, a predicate is
>   called an **invariant** to a sequence of
>   operations if the predicate always
>   evaluates at the end of the sequence
>   to the same value as before starting
>   the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

side effect-free?

Answer (score 3):

In math, a function 'f' is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) if multiple applications do not change the result.

Answer (score 2):

you mean idempotence?

Answer (score 1):

> or the action will not alter the functioning of the system...

Are you looking for ‘idempotence’?

Answer (score 1):

The "ends with -icity" part of your question makes me think you might be looking for [*monotonicity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), even though it does **not** quite match description/definition of the word. From the Wikipedia article:

> In mathematics, a monotonic function (or monotone function) is a function which preserves the given order. This concept first arose in calculus, and was later generalized to the more abstract setting of order theory.

In the following illustrations (also borrowed from the Wikipedia article) three functions are drawn:

A: [image]
    
B: [image]
    
C: [image]

A and B and both monotonic (increasing and decreasing respectively), while C is not monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an atomic block of code?

Answer (score 0):

The A in ACID.

Atomicity - states that database modifications must follow an “all or nothing” rule. Each transaction is said to be “atomic.” If one part of the transaction fails, the entire transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're describing would be a *memoryless* function. Although the term *memorylessness* is usually used for stochastic distributions, I don't quite remember if it has a programming equivalent...